# Save NSMutableArray to load when reopenning iphone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsuserdefaults, core-plot, nscoding

I have a NSMutableArray, each item in this array is different class. In each class has many field such as CPPlot, identifier,... (I am using CorePlot to develop a stock application). Now I would like to store this NSMutableArray to load when user reopen application, this will load all the chart they used before.

I try to figure out how to do that in Stackoverflow. And I found out there were 2 solutions:

NSUserDefaults

SQLite database

1. In NSUserDefaults, when I want to store NSMutableArray, I must implement with NSKeyedArchiver to archive and unarchive array object, also do NSCoding protocol for each item in array object. But I can not do this solution because in each item, it has some fields from CorePlot library, so that I can not use NSCoding to these fields.
2. SQLite database, I can not use this solution because each item in array object is different class.

I would like to ask if any other solution to solve this problem?

I hope my words are clear enough to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you figure out what kind of data is at the root of your CorePlot objects. If it is integers, then simply store them in NSUserDefaults, and then simply rebuild your NSMutableArray on re-opening the app. Another option is to store your items in a separate plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to save:

```
- (NSArray *)applicationDataFromFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirecotiresInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,
                                                         YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSArray *myData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
    return myData;
}

- (BOOL)saveToFileForStringArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
                          toFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,
                                                         YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    if (!documentsDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return ([array writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES]);
}
```